# Android: Starting app from 'recent applications' back to last activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

I have got a problem with resume to app from 'recent applications' or run app from application list.
Always run SplashScreenActivity, but should run MainActivity.

My Manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".utils.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    <activity
            android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
            android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


</application>
```

Comment: This is a known issue with the framework: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72299534, there is a workaround with checking in splash screen's oncreate and finishing before anything else.

Comment: Thanks for help. I modified my code and in MainActivity override SaveInstanceState and it works :)